# Use "days ago" instead of date

Tags: python, time, discord, discord.py

I'm currently working on a discord bot that shows me user information like ID, Name, and that stuff, and I added a Join date and an account create date, they are working fine but I also want to include a "days ago" instead of the blank date.

Here is the code I have:

```
from unicodedata import name
import discord
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.',intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready!")

@bot.command(name="user")
async def user(ctx,user:discord.Member=None):

    if user==None:
        user=ctx.author

    rlist = []
    for role in user.roles:
        if role.name != "@everyone":
            rlist.append(role.mention)
    b = ','.join(rlist)
    
    if rlist:
        b = ','.join(rlist)
    else:
        b = "No roles"


    embed = discord.Embed(colour=user.color,timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)

    embed.set_author(name=f"User Info - {user}"),
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar.url),
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Requested by - {ctx.author}',
    icon_url=ctx.author.avatar.url)

    embed.add_field(name='ID:' ,value=user.id,inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Name:' ,value=user.display_name,inline=False)

    embed.add_field(name='Created at:' ,value=datetime.strftime(user.created_at, "%#d/%m/%Y"), inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Joined at:' ,value=datetime.strftime(user.joined_at, "%#d/%m/%Y"), inline=False)
    
    embed.add_field(name='Bot?' ,value=user.bot,inline=False)

    embed.add_field(name=f'Roles:({len(rlist)})',value=''.join([b]),inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Top Role:' ,value=user.top_role.mention,inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I already tried

```
    duration = dt.datetime.now() - user.joined_at 

    hours, remainder = divmod(int(duration .total_seconds()), 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)

    await ctx.send(f"Joined before {days}d, {hours}h, {minutes}m, {seconds}s")
```

This one does not work, I think it has to do with the time zones, I tried to remove time zone awareness but that also did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```py
joined_at = user.joined_at.timestamp()
delta = int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp()) - int(joined_at)
hours, remainder = divmod(delta, 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)
```

Comment: hello im getting an error back because of invalid string:
'''
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: Invalid format string'''

I called it like this:     embed.add_field(name='test:' ,value=f'joined_at',inline=False)

Comment: you only need the "days ago" right? then `embed.add_field(name='Test:', value=f'{days} days ago', inline=False)` @RyuuDev

Comment: This is what im getting: main.py", line 31, in user joined_at = user.joined_at.strftime('%s') ValueError: Invalid format string

Comment: @RyuuDev probably because datetime doesn't support `%s` for some reason, Searched for alternative. You can use `.timestamp()` instead of `.strftime('%s')`

Comment: seems to work now, one more question what do I need to do to add the ```f'{days} days ago'``` behind ```embed.add_field(name='Joined at:' ,value=datetime.strftime(user.joined_at, "%#d/%m/%Y", inline=False)``` I tried just adding it like this ```embed.add_field(name='Joined at:' ,value=datetime.strftime(user.joined_at, "%#d/%m/%Y", "("'{days} days ago'")"), inline=False) ``` but it doesnt work

Comment: @RyuuDev the syntax is wrong. just do it simple like `embed.add_field(name='Joined at:', value=f"{user.joined_at.strftime('%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p')} ({days} days ago)", inline=False)`

Comment: uh, yeah I figured that out, thanks anyways :)